# With useEffect, how can I skip applying an effect upon the initial render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With React's new Effect Hooks, I can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven't changed between re-renders - Example from React's docs:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes
```

But the example above applies the effect upon initial render, and upon subsequent re-renders where `count` has changed. How can I tell React to skip the effect on the initial render?

Comment: Have you looked into `React.useMemo`?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

As the guide states,

> The Effect Hook, useEffect, adds the ability to perform side effects from a function component. It serves the same purpose as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount in React classes, but unified into a single API.

In this example from the guide it's expected that `count` is 0 only on initial render:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

So it will work as `componentDidUpdate` with additional check:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (count)
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]);
```

This is basically how custom hook that can be used instead of `useEffect` may work (updated for the use with strict mode):

```
function useDidUpdateEffect(fn, inputs) {
  const isMountingRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMountingRef.current = true;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMountingRef.current) {
      return fn();
    } else {
      isMountingRef.current = false;
    }
  }, inputs);
}
```

Comment: Where is the suggestion for `useRef` over `setState`? I don't see it on this page and I would like to understand why.

Comment: @rob-gordon This was a comment that was deleted after the answer was updated. The reasoning is that useState woukld result in unnecessary component update.

Comment: This approach works, but it violates the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps linter rule.  I.e. fn is not given in the array of deps.  Anyone have an approach that doesn't violate React best practices?

Comment: @JustinLang React linter rules != best practices, they only try to address common hook problems. ESLint rules aren't intelligent and may result in false positives or negatives. As long as the logic behind a hook is correct, a rule can be safely ignored with eslint-disable or eslint-disable-next comment. In this case `fn` shouldn't be provided as input. See the explanation, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies . If something inside `fn` introduces deps, it's more like they should be provided as `inputs` directly.

Comment: **Note**: If you are using multiple useEffects that check for didMountRef, make sure only the last one (on bottom) is setting didMountRef to false. React goes through useEffects in order!

Comment: This worked for me but I had to disable React.StrictMode because it renders components twice, which circumvented the intention of the ref guard.

Comment: I made a hook for that called `useDidMount()` and then I am using it as `const didMount = useDidMount()`, where `didMount` is a boolean

Comment: This works but if you need a cleanup function it doesn't work for me. Is there a way?, event though we are returning func(); it will not call the cleanup function when using this hook.

Comment: @Madtin Can you provide a demo? There's supposed to be no inconsistencies due to the simplicity of code, `return fn()` just returns cleanup function, considering that `fn` returns it

Comment: Just in case someone needs it in Typescript, the type for `fn` is `EffectCallback` and the type for `inputs` is `DependencyList` (and is optional in `useEffect`). Both types can be imported from `react`.

Comment: This won't work in strict mode, right?

Comment: @BorisBoskovic I didn't notice any problems with strict mode myself, despite the comment above. I wouldn't actually expect them because the hook follows normal lifecycle of a component. If there's a problem associated with it that can be reproduced, please, notify me, I'll try to check.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry for late response, It actually worked as expected. I was doing it wrong.

Comment: @EstusFlask the effect will actually run during first render under Strict mode, because react does extra cleanup - setup cycle. Reproduced here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-tharp-3sdz4x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ondrej.par, you forgot to use the <Component/> in your sandbox.
@EstusFlask I can confirm that this is an issue. 
React seems to preserve the mutated ref when doing the double cycle in strict mode.

Comment: @Tomek ondrej.par Thanks for the notice, updated with a safer implementation

Answer (score 116):

Here's a custom hook that just provides a boolean flag to indicate whether the current render is the first render (when the component was mounted). It's about the same as some of the other answers but you can use the flag in a `useEffect` or the render function or anywhere else in the component you want. Maybe someone can propose a better name.

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useIsMount = () => {
  const isMountRef = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    isMountRef.current = false;
  }, []);
  return isMountRef.current;
};
```

You can use it like:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useIsMount } from './useIsMount';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const isMount = useIsMount();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMount) {
      console.log('First Render');
    } else {
      console.log('Subsequent Render');
    }
  });

  return isMount ? <p>First Render</p> : <p>Subsequent Render</p>;
};
```

And here's a test for it if you're interested:

```js
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

import { useIsMount } from '../useIsMount';

describe('useIsMount', () => {
  it('should be true on first render and false after', () => {
    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useIsMount());
    expect(result.current).toEqual(true);
    rerender();
    expect(result.current).toEqual(false);
    rerender();
    expect(result.current).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

Our use case was to hide animated elements if the initial props indicate they should be hidden. On later renders if the props changed, we did want the elements to animate out.

Comment: Import changed from `react-hooks-testing-library` to `@testing-library/react-hooks` https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: Why did you choose "isMount" and not "didMount" or "isMounted" ?

Comment: Guess I was thinking about whether the current render is the render where the mount was happening. Ya I agree, it sounds a little weird coming back to it now. But it's true on the first render and false after so your suggestions sound misleading. `isFirstRender` could work.

Comment: Thanks for the hook! I agree with @ScottyWaggoner , `isFirstRender` is a better name

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using your hook the way like first value false, after mounting true and renamed didMount :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this ! I totally agree about the name. `isFirstRender` makes sense. I have used it in my project with this name already =)

Comment: Recently I used this with Next.js to wait until after hydration to update dates to a local timezone to prevent hydration errors where the client UI didn't match what was server rendered. I named it `useIsHydrated`, flipped the initial state, and used `useState` instead of `useRef` to force a rerender when the value changed.

Comment: React 18: "no" :/

Answer (score 39):

I found a solution that is more simple and has no need to use another hook, but it has drawbacks.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // skip initial render
  return () => {
    // do something with dependency
  }
}, [dependency])
```

This is just an example that there are others ways of doing it if your case is very simple.

The drawback of doing this is that you can't have a cleanup effect and will only execute when the dependency array changes the second time.

This isn't recommended to use and you should use what the other answers are saying, but I only added this here so people know that there is more than one way of doing this.

## Edit:

Just to make it more clear, **you shouldn't use this** approach to solving the problem in the question (skipping the initial render), this is only for teaching purpose that shows you can do the same thing in different ways.
If you need to skip the initial render, please use the approach on other answers.

Comment: I just learned something. I didn't think this would work, then I tried and it actually does. Thank you!

Comment: React should provide a better way for this, but this issue is open on Github and the proposal is to write a custom solution yourself (which is utter non-sense).

Comment: The problem with that one is that it will be executed on unMount as well, which is not perfect.

Comment: @ncesar if this was the only answer that worked, probably you are doing something wrong, because the other answer are the correct ones and mine is just for teaching purpos

Answer (score 37):

I use a regular state variable instead of a ref.

```js
// Initializing didMount as false
const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false)

// Setting didMount to true upon mounting
useEffect(() => { setDidMount(true) }, [])

// Now that we have a variable that tells us wether or not the component has
// mounted we can change the behavior of the other effect based on that
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
  if (didMount) document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`
}, [count])
```

We can refactor the didMount logic as a custom hook like this.

```js
function useDidMount() {
  const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => { setDidMount(true) }, [])

  return didMount
}
```

Finally, we can use it in our component like this.

```js
const didMount = useDidMount()

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
  if (didMount) document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`
}, [count])
```

---

**UPDATE** Using useRef hook to avoid the extra rerender (Thanks to @TomEsterez for the suggestion)

This time our custom hook returns a function returning our ref's current value. U can use the ref directly too, but I like this better.

```js
function useDidMount() {
  const mountRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => { mountRef.current = true }, []);

  return () => mountRef.current;
}
```

Usage

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const didMount = useDidMount();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (didMount()) // do something
    else // do something else
  })

  return (
    <div>something</div>
  );
}
```

On a side note, I've never had to use this hook and there are probably better ways to handle this which would be more aligned with the React programming model.

Comment: `useRef` is better suited for that because `useState` will cause an additional and useless render of the component: https://codesandbox.io/embed/youthful-goldberg-pz3cx

Comment: you have an error in your `useDidMount` Function. You have to encapsulate the `mountRef.current = true` in `useEffect()` with curly brackets `{ ...}`. Leaving them is like writing `return mountRef.current = true`, and that cause an error like `An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned: true`

Answer (score 30):

### Let me introduce to you [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use).

`npm install react-use`

#### Wanna run:

*only after first render*? -------> `useUpdateEffect`

*only once*? ------->  `useEffectOnce`

*check is it first mount*?  -------> `useFirstMountState`

Want to run effect with *deep compare*, *shallow compare* or *throttle*? and much more [here](https://github.com/streamich/react-use).

Don't want to install a library? Check the [code](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useUpdateEffect.ts) & copy. (maybe a `star` for the good folks there too)

Best thing is *one less thing for you to maintain.*

Comment: Looks like a really good package

Comment: Fantastic resource, so glad I found this!

Comment: Unclear what's the difference between `useUpdateEffect` & `useUpdateEffect`? Both run only once

Comment: It's a very bloated library and it's unclear if it was made with tree-shaking in mind. Also it bloats the `node_modules` if all you need is to run `useEffect` not on mount...

Comment: `Unclear what's the difference between useUpdateEffect & useUpdateEffect? Both run only once` Do you mean `useUpdateEffect` and `useEffectOnce`? `useUpdateEffect` is exactly like `useEffect` but skip the first run. Use can see it here: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useUpdateEffect.md

Comment: For tree-shaking, you can check here: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/Usage.md
Example: You can import like this `import useUpdateEffect from "react-use/lib/useUpdateEffect"`

Answer (score 9):

A TypeScript and CRA friendly hook, replace it with `useEffect`, this hook works like `useEffect` but won't be triggered while the first render happens.

```
import * as React from 'react'

export const useLazyEffect:typeof React.useEffect = (cb, dep) => {
  const initializeRef = React.useRef<boolean>(false)

  React.useEffect((...args) => {
    if (initializeRef.current) {
      cb(...args)
    } else {
      initializeRef.current = true
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, dep)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my implementation based on Estus Flask's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180013/9449426) written in Typescript. It also supports cleanup callback.

```js
import { DependencyList, EffectCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function useDidUpdateEffect(
  effect: EffectCallback,
  deps?: DependencyList
) {
  // a flag to check if the component did mount (first render's passed)
  // it's unrelated to the rendering process so we don't useState here
  const didMountRef = useRef(false);

  // effect callback runs when the dependency array changes, it also runs
  // after the component mounted for the first time.
  useEffect(() => {
    // if so, mark the component as mounted and skip the first effect call
    if (!didMountRef.current) {
      didMountRef.current = true;
    } else {
      // subsequent useEffect callback invocations will execute the effect as normal
      return effect();
    }
  }, deps);
}
```

### Live Demo

The live demo below demonstrates the different between `useEffect` and `useDidUpdateEffect` hooks

[image: Edit 53179075/with-useeffect-how-can-i-skip-applying-an-effect-upon-the-initial-render]

Answer (score 4):

I was going to comment on the currently accepted answer, but ran out of space!

Firstly, it's important to move away from thinking in terms of lifecycle events when using functional components. Think in terms of prop/state changes. I had a similar situation where I only wanted a particular `useEffect` function to fire when a particular prop (`parentValue` in my case) changes from its initial state. So, I created a ref that was based on its initial value:

```
const parentValueRef = useRef(parentValue);
```

and then included the following at the start of the `useEffect` fn:

```
if (parentValue === parentValueRef.current) return;
parentValueRef.current = parentValue;
```

(Basically, don't run the effect if `parentValue` hasn't changed. Update the ref if it has changed, ready for the next check, and continue to run the effect)

So, although other solutions suggested will solve the particular use-case you've provided, it will help in the long run to change how you think in relation to functional components.

Think of them as primarily rendering a component based on some props.

If you genuinely need some local state, then `useState` will provide that, but don't *assume* your problem will be solved by storing local state.

If you have some code that will alter your props during a render, this 'side-effect' needs to be wrapped in a `useEffect`, but the purpose of this is to have a clean render that isn't affected by something changing as it's rendering. The `useEffect` hook will be run after the render has completed and, as you've pointed out, it's run with every render - unless the second parameter is used to supply a list of props/states to identify what changed items will cause it to be run subsequent times.

Good luck on your journey to Functional Components / Hooks! Sometimes it's necessary to unlearn something to get to grips with a new way of doing things :)
This is an excellent primer: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) to run use effect after mount.

```
const useEffectAfterMount = (cb, dependencies) => {
  const mounted = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted.current) {
      return cb();
    }
    mounted.current = true;
  }, dependencies); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
};
```

Here is the `typescript` version:

```
const useEffectAfterMount = (cb: EffectCallback, dependencies: DependencyList | undefined) => {
  const mounted = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted.current) {
      return cb();
    }
    mounted.current = true;
  }, dependencies); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
};
```

Example:

```
useEffectAfterMount(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count])
```

Comment: You have inversed true and false, it's ```const mounted = useRef(false)``` and then ```mounted.current = true```

Answer (score 2):

1、I choose the npm package *ahooks* to solve my issue, you should run `npm i ahooks` first.
2、Then in your code

```
  import { useUpdateEffect } from "ahooks";
  useUpdateEffect(() => {
    // do something if deps change but skipping the initial render.
  }, deps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is similar to above, just a little cleaner way i prefer.

```
const [isMount, setIsMount] = useState(true);
useEffect(()=>{
        if(isMount){
            setIsMount(false);
            return;
        }
        
        //Do anything here for 2nd render onwards
}, [args])
```

Comment: This is not an ideal way of doing this as setting state causes another render

Comment: Causes a **needless** re-render. `useRef` solution is preferable.