# Prevent useEffect hook from running on ComponentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This code runs when `name` is changed (as it should) but it also runs when the component first loads. How can I have it run only on subsequent changes to `name` and not the first time the default value is set?

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  alert('Hi ' + name);
}, [name]);
```

Comment: you can check some approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179075/with-useeffect-how-can-i-skip-applying-an-effect-upon-the-initial-render)

Comment: afaik, the react guide defines `The Effect Hook, useEffect, adds the ability to perform side effects from a function component. It serves the same purpose as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount in React classes, but unified into a single API.` so not sure if you can prevent it from running during `componentDidMount()` so maybe you are looking for `useLayoutEffect` i think. just did a quick google https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254028/6141587

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a ref you can track the first render, set to false after the first render.

```
const firstRenderRef = useRef(true);
const [name, setName] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  if (firstRenderRef.current) {
    firstRenderRef.current = false;
  } else {
    alert('Hi ' + name);
  }
}, [name]);
```

I'd factor this into a custom hook though

```
const useSkipFirstEffect = (callback, dependencies) => {
  const firstRenderRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRenderRef.current) {
      firstRenderRef.current = false;
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }, [callback, ...dependencies]);
};
```

Usage:

```
useSkipFirstEffect(() => {
  alert('SkipFirstEffect: Hi ' + name);
}, [name]);
```

[image: Edit useEffect skip first render]

Comment: A question from someone who's learning React — is there a reason you need _useRef()_? Would a boolean not achieve the same thing?

Comment: @Rich This code ***is*** using a boolean. If you are asking why we store the boolean value in a React ref, this is because in React function components all local variables are redeclared each time the component is rendered, i.e. each time the function is called. The ref is a bucket that we can mutate at-will and the value persists through rerenders. Also, updating a React ref doesn't trigger rerenders (*such as would be case if we used local state to track the initial render*).

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways of skipping effect on initial render(like ref and using a variable). What I generally use and found the most simplest way is using the `return` of useEffect. It seems to me this is a bit hackish way but it works -

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  //don't do anything on initial render
  return () => {
      alert('Hi ' + name);
   }
}, [name]);
```

Now this will run only when dependency `name` changes. I am not sure if it's recommended but it always worked for me without any problems. Leaving here in case it helps.

> NOTE:: This will also run on component unmount change. To prevent that
>   you can just use a check.

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the custom hook to re-run multiples times because you are re-creating a new array in the array of dependencies `[callback, ...dependencies]` I'd change it like so:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function useEffectSkipFirst(callback, dependencies) {
  const firstRenderRef = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRenderRef.current) {
      firstRenderRef.current = false
      return
    }
    callback()
  }, dependencies)
}

export default useEffectSkipFirst
```