# Does the componentDidMount useEffect hook run when comming back from another react-link from the same project?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Inside a React Project. Let's say you start at the `FavoriteList`-page, from there you go to the `ItemInfo`-page. My question is, when you go back to the Favorites-page, is the `useEffect(() => {}, [])` hook (similar to the `ComponentDidMount`) load again?
Because it's not loading for me  :'(
It only loads the very first time.

Comment: Share your code so we can help you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "you go to the ItemInfo-page", are you using react-router? However, it appears that your component isn't unmounting. Try running the following code: `useEffect(() => {
  return () => console.log("unmounted")
}, [])` and check if it triggers the unmount.

Comment: Hi guys thank you very much! My problem was that I wasn't correctly updating my component state.

Comment: @MustKillBill, that log inside the useEffect was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use effect always runs on the first render of a component, then after that depends on what you pass as your second argument.

If you want useEffect to run ONLY on the first render of the component, use this:

```
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

If you want useEffect to run on EVERY render, use this (no second argument):

```
useEffect(() => {})
```

If you want useEffect to run on the first render of the component, AND on state(s) changes, use this:

```
useEffect(() => {}, [state, anotherState])
```

If you are trying to avoid useEffect rendering on the first render, you need to use a UseRef hook. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179075/with-useeffect-how-can-i-skip-applying-an-effect-upon-the-initial-render) will tell you how to go about doing this.