# Stop invoking custom hook on first render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I started having fun with custom hooks recently. I am mostly using them to fetch from api. The thing is that since I cannot really put useFetchLink inside of functions or useEffect i dont know how to prevent it from fetching after website first render. I could put some ifs in the hook but isn't there any other way?

````
***component*** 

export default function LinkShortener({ setLinkArr }) {
  const [nextLink, setNextLink] = useState();
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setNextLink(inputRef.current.value);
  };

  const { shortLink, loading, error } = useFetchLink(nextLink);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLinkArr((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      {
        id: prev.length === 0 ? 1 : prev[prev.length - 1].id + 1,
        long: nextLink,
        short: shortLink,
      },
    ]);
    inputRef.current.value = "";
  }, [shortLink, error]);

  return (
    <LinkShortenerContainer>
      <InputContainer>
        <LinkInput ref={inputRef} type="text" />
      </InputContainer>
      <Button
        size={buttonSize.medium}
        text={
          loading ? (
            <Loader />
          ) : (
            <FormattedMessage
              id="linkShortener.shortenItBtn"
              defaultMessage="Shorten It !"
            />
          )
        }
        onClick={handleClick}
      ></Button>
    </LinkShortenerContainer>
  );
}
***hook***
const useFetchLink = (linkToShorten) => {
  const [shortLink, setShortLink] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const fetchLink = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${linkToShorten}`
      );
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setShortLink(data.result.short_link);
      } else {
        throw response.status;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLink(linkToShorten);
  }, [linkToShorten]);

  const value = { shortLink, loading, error };
  return value;
};```
````

Comment: An `if` in the hook is exactly what you'd want.

Comment: if `linkToShorten` doesn't change the effect won't fire

Comment: But linkToShorten is provided with nextLink state and its being set at first render to ""

Comment: What @GiorgiMoniava said, but it would be helpful to know the entire flow of your example by seeing the JSX code as well. You could create it in CodeSandbox, StackBlitz or something similar.

Comment: @AglecikNaplecik what do you mean by "first render"? I bet the problem is hidden somewhere in the rest of the code.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, by "stop invoking custom hook" you're referring only to calling the API, i.e. the hook's `useEffect`, correct? Because you shouldn't prevent the entire hook from being called, so I'm just checking.

Comment: I have put whole component code in post. You are right, I was referring to calling the API. I want to call an API only when state nextLink is being set. Then I want to take api response and update linkArr with it. LinkArr is rendering components via map() in different component but right now linkArr is being updated after every site refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking - the standard way to avoid `useEffect` from running of 1st render is to use a `boolean` ref initialized with `false`, and toggled to `true` after first render - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180013/5157454).

However, in your case, you don't want to call the function if `linkToShorten` is empty, even if it's not the 1st render, so use an `if` inside `useEffect`.

```
const useFetchLink = (linkToShorten) => {
  const [shortLink, setShortLink] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const fetchLink = useCallback(async (linkToShorten) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${linkToShorten}`
      );
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setShortLink(data.result.short_link);
      } else {
        throw response.status;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(linkToShorten) fetchLink(linkToShorten);
  }, [fetchLink, linkToShorten]);

  const value = { shortLink, loading, error };
  return value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using directly `fetchLink` function and calling it whenever you need inside the component? I would change the hook in this way without `useEffect` inside

```
const useFetchLink = (linkToShorten) => {
  const [shortLink, setShortLink] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const fetchLink = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${linkToShorten}`
      );
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setShortLink(data.result.short_link);
      } else {
        throw response.status;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const value = { shortLink, loading, error, fetchLink };
  return value;
};
```