# localStorage start empty

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I´m doing a to do list using react and my localStorage save the items in a array at localStorage but when I refresh the page then it is empty.

[image: localStorage saving the items]

```
const SAVED_ITEMS = "savedItems";

function Todo() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let savedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(SAVED_ITEMS));
    if (savedItems) {
      setItems(savedItems);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(SAVED_ITEMS, JSON.stringify(items));
  }, [items]);
}
```

[image: index.js]

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What's the value of `savedItems` when the first useEffect function runs? The local storage key is different in your screenshot than in your code, for what that's worth.

Comment: The code you've provided works fine (although the first effect would be better as a callback passed to `useState` for the initial values of `items`), so you'll need to include more information here. Could also be something with your browser settings.

Comment: Are there any other parts of your code that updates this storage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With useEffect, how can I skip applying an effect upon the initial render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179075/with-useeffect-how-can-i-skip-applying-an-effect-upon-the-initial-render). The problem is when the 2nd effect hook runs on initial render, `items` is an empty array. You need to skip it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem...
It was happening because an update from react!
With that update, StrictMode ends up generating some unexpected behaviors.

[image: React.StrictMode]

**after comment the <react.StrictMode> the localStorage started working properly.**

[image: React.StrictMode commented]

Comment: Read [this](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).